# gnu make "leaf" prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to learn about leaf prerequisites of a target?

In this case, the leaf prerequisites of `t1` are `t3` and `foo.txt`, while `t2` is intermediary:

```
t1: t2 t3
  cat t2 t3 > t1

t2: foo.txt
  cat $< > $@
```

In this example, `t2` is strictly an intermediate repository, and t3 already exists (it is not generate-able).

How can I obtain `t3` and `foo.txt`, as leaf-targets of `t1`, from make? Is it reasonable to expect that such facility exists?

Use case: I am compiling a LaTeX document to PDF, and would like to [pdfattach](https://fossies.org/linux/poppler/utils/pdfattach.1) all the leaf prerequisites without listing them explicitly in the Makefile.

Comment: _How can I obtain `t2` and `foo.txt` from Make_: Did you mean `t3 and foo.txt`?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you want, maybe because you've mistyped some names.  Can you provide minimal, _working_ example makefile that does what you want then point out the parts that you want to obtain automatically rather than typing by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
make --dry-run --debug=a t1 | grep "Considering target"
```

and write a convoluted script to parse the output (the last line, and any entry with a greater indent than it's subsequent line would be leaves).   It sounds like you want to do access this list from within the make invocation though, but I don't think there is any built in support for this.

(you could do a recursive make call from within a recipe -- not efficient, but may work).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the rules the prerequisites can be accessed via [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), such as `$<` and `$^`.

However, `make` must know the prerequisites in order to rebuild correctly, so there must be a list of files in a make variable. That list of files can be specified explicitly or be read from a file or another command.